# Ripping multi-angle bluray video

Tags: ffmpeg, blu-ray

I have some Bluray disks I am attempting to rip video from.  Normally I'd use ffmpeg and select a playlist to rip and be done with it.  With these discs, however, the videos make use of the alternate camera angles feature.  My understanding is that both camera angles are encoded into a single video stream.  The video codec on disc is VC-1.

I have tried just ripping the playlist as usual.  On my current machine, and playback with mpv simply will show one camera angle at a snail's pace (no hw-accelerated VC-1 decode).  Re-encoding to another format such as FFV1 will play at full speed, but again, the one camera angle.

My goal is to rip these videos with the camera angle of my choice using open source software.  I've tried opening up an .mpls file with a hex editor to peek at which .m2ts files are referenced so I can rip those individually and stitch them together, but I have not found success in ripping the individual .m2ts files.  If I set one as an input to ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i BDMV/STREAM/00000.m2ts -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v copy output.mkv`, I get back "*BDMV/STREAM/00000.m2ts: Invalid data found when processing input*".  I assume that's because it needs to be decrypted?  Not sure how to get ffmpeg to make use of libaacs to decrypt when trying to use .m2ts as input rather than .mpls

So, how can I rip specific camera angles from a bluray video using free open source software available on Linux?

Comment: Not sure if it works, but I've answered a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710210/418943) and would try makemkv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an up-to-date version of bluray_copy.  Version 1.9 is working for me.

The program I had been using to rip my blurays, `bluray_copy` from the [bluray_info](https://github.com/beandog/bluray_info) project was version 1.3, which as of today is still the latest unstable ebuild available in the gentoo repository.  With version 1.3, I failed to rip anything other than the default camera angle.

I downloaded and compiled the latest source from the git repository and that version correctly ripped the video using the camera angle passed on the command line.  I have since created a local gentoo ebuild for the latest tagged version, 1.9, and that also works as intended.